# itertools permutation set loses its data after using len(list(my_set))

Tags: python, python-itertools

```
import itertools as itt
perm_set = itt.permutations('ABC')
iter1 = len(list(perm_set))
iter2 = len(list(perm_set))
print(iter1,iter2)
```

For some reason, after 3rd line `perm_set` loses its data, so `iter1!=iter2`. Why does it loose its data after taking the length of it?

But if i do the same thing with list, it works properly.

But if i do the same thing with list, it works properly.

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
iter1 = len(list(l))
iter2 = len(list(l))
print(iter1,iter2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions in `itertools` return generators. Generators can only run once. After the first run, the generator is used up (no elements remain) and it will output no further elements. You can *imagine* this as a queue where you take one element out at a time and when the queue is empty, you won't be able to get any more elements from it anymore.

In case you want to use the result of a generator more than once, you should store the list or re-create the generator.

```
import itertools as itt
perm_set = itt.permutations('ABC')
perms = list(perm_set)
iter1 = len(perms)
iter2 = len(perms)
print(iter1,iter2)
```

or

```
import itertools as itt
perm_set = itt.permutations('ABC')
iter1 = len(list(perm_set))
perm_set = itt.permutations('ABC')
iter2 = len(list(perm_set))
print(iter1,iter2)
```

Note, generators are lazy, they generate an element at the time when you ask for the next one. That's also why you cannot directly query their length. A list instead contains all elements at once, and consequently uses more memory than a generator usually would.

Answer (score 2):

`permutations` returns a lazy iterator. This object generates the permutation tuples "on-the-fly". Once it reaches its end, it is exhausted. Any "consumption" (read: *iteration* aka looping over it, turning it into a list/set/etc., counting its elements) will exhaust it, after which it is "empty". If you want to repeatedly iterate it, turn it into a list first, or if memory is an issue, get a *new* `permutations` object.